# Java Thread.isInterrupted() returns false even when there are no blocking methods

Tags: java, android, concurrency, interrupt

I've been working with java threads and I'm confused with `Thread.interrupt()` behaviour. As I learned from [this ibm article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html), if a thread is executing some blocking method (like `sleep()`) at the moment when `interrupt()` is called on it, an exception will be thrown and the `interrrupted` flag is going to be cleaned (set to `false`). But if there's no such a blocking method being executed, then the `interrrupted` flag is going to be true, so I can use it in a condition for breaking an endless loop.

The problem is that it doesn't actually work this way. When I call `interrupt()` on the thread I want to stop and which doesn't do anything except for displaying logs in an endless loop (so no `sleep()` or `wait()`), the loop doesn't really stop since `isInterrupted()` returns false. Why does that happen? Here's some code sample:

```
exoPlayer.addListener(new ExoPlayer.EventListener() {
            Thread positionChecker;

            @Override
            public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
                Log.d("TAG", "onPlayerStateChanged");
                if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_READY) {
                    if (playWhenReady) {
                        positionChecker = new Thread() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                while (!isInterrupted()) {
                                    Log.d("TAG", "isInterrupted = " + isInterrupted());
                                }
                            }
                        };
                        positionChecker.start();
                    }
                    if (!playWhenReady) {
                        if (positionChecker != null) {
                            Log.d("TAG", "Interrupting the thread");
                            positionChecker.interrupt();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

`Log.d("TAG", "isInterrupted = " + isInterrupted());` always prints "isInterrupted = false", even after calling `positionChecker.interrupt();`

Comment: Let assume that it's changed to true...  So,  Thread exits the loop and log statement is not called...

Comment: It's never changed to true, after `positionChecker.interrupt()` is called I still can see logs printing "isInterrupted = false"